# Sample Project On NService Bus scheduler

Tags: nservicebus

I have one requirement in my current project, where, I need to implement NService bus scheduler. As I am new to Nservice bus scheduler implementation, please raise your hand, if any one is having knowledge about this, please share your thoughts on any useful link also will be helpful.

Thanks in advance

Vimal

Answer (score 5):

The NserviceBus Scheduler is quite easy to work with.

As an example, here's a snippet:

```
// 'Schedule' is an instance class that can be resolved from the container.
// To send a message every 5 minutes
schedule.Every(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5), () => bus.Send(new CallLegacySystem()));

// Name a schedule task and invoke it every 5 minutes
schedule.Every(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5), "MyCustomTask", SomeCustomMethod);
```

Take note though that this scheduler is message based, not time based. Meaning that when a task is scheduled to be executed at time X, it is not *executed* at time X, but rather queued at that time.  See:

> Since the scheduler uses the queuing mechanism, it does have some side effects on the timelines of scheduled tasks. When a task is scheduled to be run at a given time it is not "executed at that time", it is instead "queued at that time" to be executed. In most cases this distinction will have no noticeable effect on the behavior of the scheduling API. However in high load systems the fact that a scheduled task is added to the back of the queue can result in a noticeable delay between the "time the task has been request to be run" and the "time the task is actually executed".

If you need more help, the documentation can be found [here](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/scheduling/) and is quite thorough.